# mysql search words in text column sorted by # world matched

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Problem:

the text input will be 3 or 4 words,
i want show the field who contain at least one of these words.

for example if the words are "alpha bravo charlie delta" i want allow the results

```
CHARLIE BRAVO
my name is CHARLIE
what is ALPHAness
ALPHA and DELTA
adDELTAs
BRAVO
DELTA and ALPHA and BRAVO
bbbBRAVOooo CHARLIEeeee
```

no problem till here, i use the query:

```
select * from subject where name like '%alpha%'
or name like '%bravo%' or name like '%charlie%'
or name like '%delta%
```

but i want show the results in a particular ORDER,
the results are more relevant when

- more words occurance more relevante result should be,
  so "CHARLIE BRAVO" shows up before "BRAVO"

i found a solution for that

```
select  *
,       (
          (char_length(col1) - char_length(replace(col1,'alpha','')))
          / char_length('alpha')
  +
          (char_length(col1) - char_length(replace(col1,'bravo','')))
          / char_length('bravo')
  +
          (char_length(col1) - char_length(replace(col1,'delta','')))
          / char_length('delta')
  +
          (char_length(col1) - char_length(replace(col1,'charlie','')))
          / char_length('charlie')
         ) as Occurances
from    YourTable
order by
        Occurances desc
```

but i need other order rules:

- if the record begin with a searched word is more relevant es."ALPHA and..."
- if a word in the record begin with a searched word is more relevant es."what is ALPHAness"
- searched word inside the record es."adDELTAs"

i find a solution for these order problem too but,
HOW TO combine both?

```
 select id, name
    from subjects
    where name like '%alpha%'
    order by 
      name like 'alpha%' desc,
      ifnull(nullif(instr(name, ' alpha'), 0), 99999),
      ifnull(nullif(instr(name, 'alpha'), 0), 99999),
      name;
```

so to conclude if I search "alpha bravo" the results should be:

```
DELTA and ALPHA and BRAVO (contain both words so is the first)
ALPHA and DELTA (begin with the first word searched)
BRAVO (begin with the second word searched)
what is ALPHAness (has the first word searched as begin of a word)
CHARLIE BRAVO (has the second word searched as begin of a word)
bbbBRAVOooo charlieeee (has the second word searched inside)
```

PS i need case insensitive and without distinction with accented letters òàùèìé so è = e

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a stored function to calculate the weight to be used in the ordering.

E.g. initially weight is 0.

If a word is found in the field weight+=1000

If the word is from the beginning of the record weight+=100

If the word is from the beginning of the word weight+=10

weight+=(amount of the words - word index) order of the word

So passing search "alpha bravo" returns

```
1000+10+1 + 1000+10 DELTA and ALPHA and BRAVO (contain both words so is the first)
1000+100+1 ALPHA and DELTA (begin with the first word searched)
1000+100 BRAVO (begin with the second word searched)
1000+10+1 what is ALPHAness (has the first word searched as begin of a word)
1000+10 CHARLIE BRAVO (has the second word searched as begin of a word)
1000 bbbBRAVOooo charlieeee (has the second word searched inside)
```

Comment: yes i need that, how i can do it? i just need a little example about # of word occurances, begin with, contains...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html MySQl string functions. You need LOCATE() and SUBSTR()

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/ describes how to create stored functions

Answer (score 0):

i find this solution, is not elegant.. but it's works

```
 select  *
,      
(
  (10*(col1 like 'alpha%'))+
  (8*(col1 like '% alpha%'))+
  (3*(col1 like '%alpha%' and col1 not like "% alpha%" and col1 not like 'alpha%'))+
   (9*(col1 like 'bravo%'))+
  (7*(col1 like '% bravo%'))+
  (3*(col1 like '%bravo%' and col1 not like "% bravo%" and col1 not like 'bravo%'))
 ) as score
from    YourTable where col1 like '%alpha%' or col1 like '%bravo%'
order by
        score desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91971/4